# Interfacing with Arducam OV2640 from Mac to deploy Image processing libraries

Tags: arduino-uno, python, mac-os, opencv

I purchased a Arducam OV2640 [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B012UXNDOY/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B012UXNDOY) however I am on a MAC. So I am not able to run the capture a image from the camera, which runs only on windows.

The example code is here, however I do not see any functions to capture an image or turn on the video streaming. https://github.com/ArduCAM/Arduino/blob/master/ArduCAM/examples/mini/ArduCAM_Mini_2MP_OV2640_functions/ArduCAM_Mini_2MP_OV2640_functions.ino

I tried sending msg to serial port 0x10,0x20 etc but no response.

I want to capture images from the camera and use it on my computer alternatively I want to run a OpenCV like library on the Arduino Module. How do I connect python code to the Arduino Module? Are there image processing models that can be deployed on the Arduino? Please help me get started.

Update: March 24th: I was able to update the code `ArduCAM_Mini_2MP_OV2640_functions.ino` to the Arduino, and read-write to the serial port through usb. However, the bytes read do not seem to ba a JPEG image. How do I understand the stream of bytes that are returned?

```
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200)
ser.write(b'8')
ser.write(b'\x10')
import time



# Read the size of the JPEG data buffer from Arduino
f = open('image.jpg', 'wb')
print('Send Pic')
i = 0
while i < 10:
    if ser.in_waiting > 0:
        data = ser.read(1)
        print("Received:", data)
        # Write the JPEG data to a file
        f.write(data)
    else:
        print(i)
        i += 1
        time.sleep(1)

f.close()
```

Comment: You said: "I want to run a OpenCV like library on the Arduino Module". There are many Arduino platforms, but likely most of them would run out of resources before any significant amount of the OpenCV library was ported to them.

Comment: That is correct; This is a hobby project. The idea is to build and deploy a model onto the board - and use it to take an action based on it.